# AngularJS : Keeping the Dom and Model in sync when using nested JQuery Sortables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do you keep the DOM and the model in sync when using nested JQuery sortables? Say I have a Controller which is has defined as follows:

```
function testCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{'name' : 'Test 1',
                   'index' : 0,
                   'values': [{'name' : 'sub test 1-1', 'index' : 0}, {'name' : 'sub test 1-2', 'index' : 1}]},
                   {'name' : 'Test 2',
                   'index' : 1,
                   'values': [{'name' : 'sub test 2-1', 'index' : 0}, {'name' : 'sub test 2-2', 'index' : 1}]}
   ];

   $scope.orderProp = 'index';
}
```

Now I want to show the first level data and the second level data in JQuery sortables using the following template :

```
<ul ng-sortable='data'>
    <li ng-repeat="d in data | orderBy:orderProp">
        <p>{{d.name}}</p>
        <ul ng-Sub-Sortable="d.values">
            <li ng-repeat="sub in d.values">{{sub.eg}}</li> 
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I use directives to specify the two different types of sortable lists as they do differ in behaviour (removed from below for brevity):

```
app.directive("ngSortable", function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){                  
            element.sortable();
        }
    };
}

app.directive("ngSubSortable", function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){                  
            element.sortable();
        }
    };
}
```

Now when the user sorts the list how do I update the model to ensure that the indexes are correct and therefore the lists are output correctly in the future?

Comment: Have you looked into https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/pull/119 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method I have found for keeping the model in sync with the DOM for items with position dependant data in a nested sortable is to add the current position to each element as an attribute as follows :

```
<ul ng-sortable='data'>
    <li ng-sortable-index="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="d in data | orderBy:orderProp">
        <p>{{d.name}}</p>
        <ul ng-Sub-Sortable="d.values">
            <li ng-sortable-index="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="sub in d.values">{{sub.eg}}</li> 
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Then in the directives where the jQuery sortable is initialised the sortable update method should be specified as follows :

```
element.sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var model = scope.$eval(attrs.ngSubSortable);

        // loop through items in new order
        element.children().each(function(index) {
            // get old item index
            var oldIndex = parseInt($(this).attr("ng-sortable-index"), 10);
            model[oldIndex].index = index;
         });

         scope.$apply();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use ngModel to sync data with dom

You could try this one: 
https://github.com/JimLiu/Angular-NestedSortable